# back up folder and always having 7 folders using ANT

Tags: ant

i have some requirements for my ant script.

My ant script does checking out of `"mobile"`folder from version control software into a `"Nightly Build"` folder and i have some requirements:

1. If inside `"Nightly Build"` folder, there exist a folder `"mobile"` folder, I would want to back up that older folder by renaming the folder with `"mobile" + timestamp`
2. `"Nightly Build"` folder should always contain 7 such `"mobile"` folders only. This means that if there are 8 `"mobile"`, I will need to delete the oldest `"mobile"` folder

Is this possible in ANT script(performed sequentially) and how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion - this just deletes any that are more than seven days old, rather than keeping a fixed number of builds.

```
<property name="builds.dir" value="Nightly Build" />
<property name="build.dir" value="mobile" />

<tstamp>
    <format property="cutoff.7"
            offset="-7"
            unit="day"
            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"/>
</tstamp>

<tstamp>
    <format property="suffix"
            pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmss"/>
</tstamp>

<move file="${builds.dir}/${build.dir}"
      tofile="${builds.dir}/${build.dir}.${suffix}"
      failonerror="false" />

<delete>
    <dirset dir="${builds.dir}" id="old.dirs" includes="${build.dir}.*">
        <date datetime="${cutoff.7}" when="before" checkdirs="yes" />
    </dirset>
</delete>

</project>
```

See the Ant [`tstamp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) and [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[Martin Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183172/martin-clayton) has the right answer for what you're asking.

However, I suggest you look into [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) for your build processing. Jenkins can handle everything you mentioned, and does it in a way that is implementation independent. For example, what if you changed version control systems or your build requirements changed? You would be forced to change your build.xml file to keep up.

With Jenkins, your build.xml file is only for building. Jenkins can handle the checkout, build, saving your build artifacts, and reporting errors and testing and deployments. Thus, if you change your version control or build requirements, instead of mucking with your build.xml (and possibly breaking it), you only need to change a parameter in the Jenkins task.

Download Jenkins and take a look at it. It's simple to setup and easy to understand. Plus, it contains dozens of plugins that can extend it. Want to publish Java Docs? Want to run Checkstyle or Findbugs? Want to see the JUnit test results? You can do that in Jenkins.